# Regex Pattern: How to check for word with nothing on either side

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern to check for a word (e.g. "def") with nothing on either side.

Have tried using the \b method but it treats non-word characters (e.g. "|", |!| as boundaries.

```
$text ="abc|def|ghi";

$pattern = "/\bdef\b/";

if (preg_match($pattern, $text)) {echo "yes";}

else{echo "no";}
```

The above yields "yes".  But I want it to check the word def with nothing on either side. What should be added to the pattern to achieve that?  Thanks

Comment: Probably you need: `/(?<!\S)def(?!\S)/`

Comment: Thanks. but it didn't work for me even when def has nothing on either side.

Comment: check demo in my answer. It will match `def`

Comment: Try:  /\s+def\s+/

Comment: Swadeep: thanks,  /\s+def\s+/ works as well.

Comment: anubhava: Thank you, It works. Surprised really because capital \S denotes any character that is *NOT* a whitespace. How come?

Comment: Sin answered your query below my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I want it to check the word def with nothing on either side. What should be added to the pattern to achieve that?

You are most probably looking for a regex with lookahead and a lookbehind:

```
/(?<!\S)def(?!\S)/
```

Lookarounds used are:

- `(?!<\S)`: Lookbehind to assert failure if there is a non-space character before
- `(?!\S)`: Lookahead to assert failure if there is a non-space character ahead

[More on lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SLo6ia/1)

Comment: A negative of a negative is a positive, like `[^\S]` equals `\s`. In this case the _negative_ is being marshaled by a negative assertion. This has the added benefit of returning _true_ at BOS and EOS.

Comment: I would definitely recommend bookmarking this tool, it's great for testing and reference. https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

The (or one) issue is this:

```
$pattern = "/\bdef\b/";
```

The escape `\b` is not defined in PHP. Test it with `echo "\n"` The result is a line feed.

Try either

```
$pattern = "/\\bdef\\b/";
```

or

```
$pattern = '/\bdef\b/';
```